# Vuex store module name is adding to state

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I'm using module approach in vue store. when I add the imported file to modules object, Module state is wrapped inside the module name.

This is my auth.js file

```
import axios from 'axios';
import router from "../../routes/routes"
export default{
    state: {
    user: null
    },
mutations : {
  SetUser(state, user){
      state.user = user;
   },
  removeUser(state){
      state.user = null
   }
},
actions: {
  async Login({commit}, payload){
  
     },
   async logout({commit}){
    }
  },
getters: {
   isLoggedIn(state) {
        return state.user !== null;
    },
 }
}
```

This is my store.js

```
 import Vue from 'vue';
 import Vuex from 'vuex';
 Vue.use(Vuex);
 import auth from "./modules/auth"
 export default new Vuex.Store({
      modules: {
          auth
       }
   });
```

state should be user:{} but it's showing like this.

[image]

Comment: but you're not adding the state to the store, are you? You should add the `state` field inside `new Vuex.Store({})`I think. But in your code snippet `store.js` you only import `auth`.

Comment: I'm adding state to the auth.js and exporting it to store. this is the file that is holding everything state, mutations, actions, getters.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm using module approach in vue store. when I add the imported file to modules object, Module state is wrapped inside the module name.

That's the expected behavior of your code when you use modules. The state will be wrapped in the module field inside the top state.

Getters defined inside a module (like `isLoggedIn` in your case) get that module's state as the first param (and root state as the third).  That's why `state.user` is actually working inside that getter, even if, in your store, the real path to user is `state.auth.user`.

If you want `user` to be part of the `state` directly, you should define it as part of the store's state, not the auth module.

On the other hand, while the state of every module is placed inside that module, getters are not. So you can call `this.$store.getters.isLoggedIn` and it will work.